# does resolutionStrategy affect the dependent lib

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Having a project which itself is using supportLib version 0f 27.1.1.

It has dependencies on a few libs,  not sure from which one causes this error:

> Execution failed for task ':demo:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.2) from [com.android.support:support-emoji-appcompat:26.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35
>       is also present at [com.android.support:percent:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-25:38 to override.

after added this resolutionStrategy:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion "${versions.support}"  //<== versions.support is 27.1.1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the error goes away.

I guess it says this project should be using 27.1.1 regardless if there is dependencies who may use different one.

Question is will this also force the dependent libs to use 27.1.1, which may not be work against this version of 27.1.1?

or it only affects this project itself?

Answer (score 0):

it changes the version numbers for requested group `com.android.support` and there are no "different versions" of version `27.1.1`. one can also define the version numbers in the `Manifest.xml` `<application>` tag, with `tools:replace`:

```
<meta-data
   android:name="android.support.VERSION"
   android:value="27.1.1"
   tools:replace="android:value"/>
```

Comment: thanks @Martin, I am still not completely clear that whether the resolutionStrategy with `details.useVersion "27.1.1"` (in this case for the com.android.support) will affect what version of the dependent lib is using. i.e.  if the lib was coded for 26.0.1,  will it now be forced to running against   the specified 27.1.1?

Comment: those support libraries usually work with a range of 2-3 major version numbers; one just cannot add a library in more than one version, per package... while the XML above is exactly what the error message proposes; adding  that should enable you to remove that manual resolution-strategy override altogether.